# Problems with #import of .NET out-of-proc server

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

In C++ program, I am trying to #import TLB of .NET out-of-proc server.

I get errors like:

> z:\server.tlh(111) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetType'
>
> z:\server.tlh(111) : error C2501: '_TypePtr' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
>
> z:\server.tli(74) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'tag::id'
>
> z:\server.tli(74) : error C2433: '_TypePtr' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
>
> z:\server.tli(74) : error C2501: '_TypePtr' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
>
> z:\server.tli(74) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end of file found

The TLH looks like:

```
_bstr_t GetToString();
VARIANT_BOOL Equals (const _variant_t & obj);
long GetHashCode();
_TypePtr GetType();
long Open();
```

I am not really interested in the having the base object .NET object methods like GetType(), Equals(), etc. But GetType() seems to be causing problems.

Some google research indicates I could `#import mscorlib.tlb` (or put it in path), but I can't get that to compile either.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added no_namespace and raw_interfaces_only to my #import:

```
#import "server.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
```

Also using TLBEXP.EXE instead of REGASM.EXE seems to help this issue.

Comment: TLBEXP didn't help me, raw_interfaces_only did. Why the code example contains named_guids instead of raw_interfaces_only?

Answer (score 3):

```
#import "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb"
```

Was the solution for me.

Comment: Recently, I had to use this `#import "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb" rename("or", "or2") rename("ReportEvent", "ReportEvent2") no_namespace
`

Answer (score 1):

Often, when MSVC compile COM source to a `TLB`, there'll be hints left behind like:

```
#import "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb"
```

You should add that to `stdafx.h` before the line

```
#import "your_own.tlb"
```

After that, basic types like `_Type`, `_ObjRef` will be added to your project for the prototypes generated.

I hope that solves your problem.

but the bigger problem is that after everything is done, there might be runtime errors when you call a Ptr in you program

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to use

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
```

Here is [another discussion](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.cx/2004-05/msg00016.html) about the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your C# class doesn't have this attribute:

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] <-- Seems to cause errors in C++ with _TypePtr

Comment: Any idea of why this is happening?